# Unable to print new lines in json axios request

Tags: javascript, post, axios

I am using an unofficial API for `https://carbon.now.sh` -- [Carbon-API](https://github.com/cyberboysumanjay/Carbon-API).

Now I want new lines to be printed in the output by the API.

Here is my code:

```
const axios = require("axios");
const fs = require("fs");
const blob = require("cross-blob");
var url = require("url");
 x = async (msg)=> {
async function downloadFile(fileUrl, outputLocationPath) {
  const writer = fs.createWriteStream(outputLocationPath);
console.log(msg.content)
  return axios({
    method: "POST",
    url: fileUrl,
    data: {code : "sometext\\n\\n holla"},
    responseType: "stream",
  }).then((response) => {
    //ensure that the user can call `then()` only when the file has
    //been downloaded entirely.

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      response.data.pipe(writer);
      let error = null;
      writer.on("error", (err) => {
        error = err;
        writer.close();
        reject(err);
      });
      writer.on("close", () => {
        if (!error) {
          resolve(true);
        }
        //no need to call the reject here, as it will have been called in the
        //'error' stream;
      });
    });
  });
}

downloadFile(
  "http://00/",
  "img.png"
).then((done) => {
  console.log("done");
});
}
module.exports.x = x
```

And here is the output

[image]

As you can see there isn't a new line.

This is what the official site sends when I monitored its network calls when it saved the snippet after logging in

```
fetch("https://carbon.now.sh/api/snippets", {
  "headers": {
    "accept": "application/json",
    "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9,hi;q=0.8",
    "authorization": "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjBlYmMyZmI5N2QyNWE1MmQ5MjJhOGRkNTRiZmQ4MzhhOTk4MjE2MmIiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.eyJuYW1lIjoiQXBhY2hlIERldiIsInBpY3R1cmUiOiJodHRwczovL2F2YXRhcnMuZ2l0aHVidXNlcmNvbnRlbnQuY29tL3UvNjg0NTk4NTU_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.WGUGwveehO_wB8QMZ3XtWmaoF6crPiLZ5ai1MTDvAD3XzGPVTvvdn64yj6bgdGCsNBK63VxcpknC6F1JkkdxBd8RKtd0UhC-sRmxLFgihdPQk0_eDp6hVvP-8fQcEgutrdff_pSyVfPUWwtRPica5c2jjU3hPfcZWdXY_JHuMhvuLosupktPq4Jw4fUYUqv_oFkubJsCDdWwz-01vHtx8U1YXz-1aG4bKMtymSeW8F2fO0QzGCTFjYhPJjtmitdG5Sd8TALZ-A9AU9nRzrY1p7esAB8pKz3l3vev0j3uzcLdj7U2AiQ4PwJh-ZpaWEZx0Eca9sjDwwW4wvvQe1PNhQ",
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "sec-ch-ua": "\"Chromium\";v=\"88\", \"Google Chrome\";v=\"88\", \";Not A Brand\";v=\"99\"",
    "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
    "sec-fetch-dest": "empty",
    "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
    "sec-fetch-site": "same-origin",
    "cookie": "_ga=GA1.3.1398702655.1614237062; _gid=GA1.3.1470596052.1614237062; _gat_gtag_UA_106958506_1=1"
  },
  "referrer": "https://carbon.now.sh/",
  "referrerPolicy": "no-referrer-when-downgrade",
  "body": "{\"code\":\"const pluckDeep = key => obj => key.split('.').reduce((accum, key) => accum[key], obj)\\n\\nconst compose = (...fns) => res => fns.reduce((accum, next) => next(accum), res)\\n\\nconst unfold = (f, seed) => {\\n  const go = (f, seed, acc) => {c\\n  }\\n  return go(f, seed, [])\\n}\"}",
  "method": "POST",
  "mode": "cors"
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You might need to use `\n` instead of `\\n`

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this by replacing the `\n` with `<br >`.

```
<p id="item">
</p>

foo = document.getElementById("item");  
  data = {code : "sometext\n\n holla"};
foo.innerHTML = data.code.replace(/\n/g,"<br>");
```

Comment: So will this replace be client side or api side?

Comment: ```
   data: {code : "sometex <br> holla"}
,```
Sending this printed <br> normally

Comment: You will receive data "sometext\n\n holla" from the server/Backend side.

Comment: My Skype: live:.cid.c49b9e216406ead4

Comment: Well the fix was to wrap the string in urlencode

Comment: didnt get u what do u mean?

Answer (score -1):

You can also concatenate `<br/>` to your JavaScript if you are displaying the data in a web browser.

To simply get a newline in your JSON, use `\n` instead of `\\n`.